# mysql.connector Exception with IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, mysql

I'm not expert in Python, I have a small script that will basically insert some data to mysql, for some reason Im getting this error from time to time without understanding what is the issue to solve it.

```
Exception in thread Thread-18:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 522, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 477, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/x/ListenerGet.py", line 143, in onMessageReceived
    dblink.execute("""INSERT INTO `messages` (`from`,`type`,`data`,`created`) VALUES (%s,1,%s,now())""",(phonenumber,messageContent.strip()))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 491, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 635, in cmd_query
    statement))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 546, in _handle_result
    elif packet[4] == '\x00':
IndexError: string index out of range

Exception in thread Thread-25:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 522, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 477, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/x/ListenerGet.py", line 143, in onMessageReceived
    dblink.execute("""INSERT INTO `whatsapp` (`from`,`type`,`data`,`created`) VALUES (%s,1,%s,now())""",(phonenumber,messageContent.strip()))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 491, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 635, in cmd_query
    statement))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 546, in _handle_result
    elif packet[4] == '\x00':
IndexError: string index out of range

Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 522, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 477, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/x/ListenerGet.py", line 143, in onMessageReceived
    dblink.execute("""INSERT INTO `messages` (`from`,`type`,`data`,`created`) VALUES (%s,1,%s,now())""",(phonenumber,messageContent.strip()))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 491, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 635, in cmd_query
    statement))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 547, in _handle_result
    return self._handle_ok(packet)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 489, in _handle_ok
    ok_packet = self._protocol.parse_ok(packet)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 160, in parse_ok
    raise errors.InterfaceError("Failed parsing OK packet.")
InterfaceError: Failed parsing OK packet.
```

My script mainly is like this:

```
import mysql.connector

SQLconn = mysql.connector.connect(
host='xxxxxx',
user='xxxx',
password="xxxx",
database='xxxxx',
use_unicode=True,
charset='utf8mb4',
autocommit=True,
time_zone='GMT'
)
dblink = SQLconn.cursor()

phonenumber = jid.split('@', 1)[0]
print("Message from %s [%s]"%(phonenumber, pushName))
dblink.execute("""INSERT INTO `messages` (`from`,`type`,`data`,`created`) VALUES (%s,1,%s,now())""",(phonenumber,messageContent.strip()))
```